Webscraping a dynamic page with rvest in R
I am wondering if it is possible to webscrape the following page
https://www.pbpstats.com/season-stats/nba?EntityType=Player&EntityId=1630169
Towards the top of the page there is a dropdown menu that lets you selecting "Scoring, Assists, .. etc". When you change what you select from this dropdown menu, the page changes but the URL doesn't.
If I would like to scrape the "Assists" tables, how would I go about doing that?
This is my code at the moment
library(rvest)

  url <- "https://www.pbpstats.com/season-stats/nba?EntityType=Player&EntityId=1630169"
  
  data <- url %>% read_html %>%  html_node('#div_entity_stats_by_season') %>% html_table()

But this gives me a 404 error
Thanks for any assistance in advance!

This site seems to have an api: https://api.pbpstats.com/docs#/Totals/get_all_season_stats_for_entity_get_all_season_stats__league__get that you can use to extract the data you want. Use this api instead of the url you have

python and R are similar but not equal in terms of efficiency in different tasks.

@AnisaB. Yes of course.

You can just query the API diretly (no need to rvest and all that):
library(httr)

headers = c(
  accept = "application/json"
)

params = list(
  EntityType = "Player",
  EntityId = "1630169"
)

res <- httr::GET(url = "https://api.pbpstats.com/get-all-season-stats/nba", httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params)

or with httr2
library(httr2)

request("https://api.pbpstats.com/get-all-season-stats/nba") |>
  req_url_query(
    EntityType = "Player",
    EntityId = "1630169"
  ) |>
  req_headers(accept = "application/json") |>
  req_perform()

this will give you all the data you're after (including the Assists table):
library(httr)

headers = c(
  Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.9,hmn;q=0.8",
  Connection = "keep-alive",
  Origin = "https://www.pbpstats.com",
  Referer = "https://www.pbpstats.com/",
  `Sec-Fetch-Dest` = "empty",
  `Sec-Fetch-Mode` = "cors",
  `Sec-Fetch-Site` = "same-site",
  `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  `sec-ch-ua` = '"Google Chrome";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"',
  `sec-ch-ua-mobile` = "?0",
  `sec-ch-ua-platform` = '"Windows"'
)

params = list(
  EntityType = "Player",
  EntityId = "1630169"
)

res <- httr::GET(url = "https://api.pbpstats.com/get-all-season-stats/nba", httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params)
res_data <- fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
all_tables <- res_data[["results"]][["Regular Season"]]


This is perfect thank you so much for helping!

@HowGoodisData if my response addressed your question fully, please accept the answer.
